# Promoting to multipart using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, saga, dissolve, multipart, singlepart

I am creating a code that aggregates neighbouring polygons if they have similar value on the field 'DN' and if they are closer than 50 m.Then I want to iterate this 3 times.

I could already get the smale ID to the polygons with this restrictions.

```
for i in range (3):
for feature in GFW_catch.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    ll = []
    for feature_n in GFW_catch.getFeatures():
        geom_n = feature_n.geometry()
        euclidean = QgsGeometry.distance(geom, geom_n)
        if abs(feature ["DN"] - feature_n ["DN"]) <= 2:
            if euclidean < 50 and feature.geometry().area() < feature_n.geometry().area():
                ll.append((feature_n.geometry().area(),feature_n ["ID"]))
    if len (ll):
        feature ["ID"] = max(ll)[1]
    GFW_catch.updateFeature(feature)
processing.runalg('saga:polygondissolve', GFW_catch,"ID", False, '2018-11-15-GFW_AR5_Forest.shp')
```

Since I did not find a code for promoting to multipars in PyQGIS, I thought about dissolving by ID with SAGA, that creates multiparts by default in the GUI. However, it is not working with the message: Error: Algorithm not found.

in https://qgis-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/shapes_polygons.html the doccumetation shows this code:

processing.runalg('saga:polygondissolve', polygons, field_1, field_2, field_3, dissolve, dissolved)

any tip?

Comment: i found this code snippet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/MultipartToSingleparts.py for 2.18. Since the documentation for [qgis3](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html) still isn't up to date, ne must use the old stuff and check, which parts are hit by an API change: https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. The previous comment looks like it should lead you to some starting code.